# How to use GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with gcloud on a server?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

What is the simplest way to use the `gcloud` command line non-interactively with a Service Account outside of GCE? Preferably without littering the file system with credentials files, which is what `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=...` does.

There are many use cases for using `gcloud` with a service account. For example, on a server, I would like to test that the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` is correctly set and has the required permissions before running my application. Or, I would like to run some setup scripts or cron scripts that perform some check with the `gcloud` command line.

Google Cloud libraries (e.g. [python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python), [java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java)) automatically use the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to authenticate to Google Cloud. But unfortunately, this command line seems to have no effect on `gcloud`. What is a clean way to use `gcloud` while leaving the filesystem intact?

```
$ GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/etc/my-service-account-4b4b6e63aaed.json gcloud alpha pubsub topics publish testtopic hello
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.pubsub.topics.publish) You do not currently have an active account selected.
Please run:

  $ gcloud auth login

to obtain new credentials, or if you have already logged in with a
different account:

  $ gcloud config set account ACCOUNT

to select an already authenticated account to use.
```

Comment: Please feel free to open a feature request on Google Public Issue Tracker with mentioning your use cases: https://issuetracker.google.com

Comment: I have created issue [38098801](https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/38098801)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`gcloud` generally does not use `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. It only has some commands to facilitate setting up these application default credentials in `gcloud auth application-default [login|revoke|print-access-token...]`.

By default `gcloud` stores its configuration in ${HOME}/.config/gcloud. It is possible to override that location by setting `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` environment variable.

Also it is possible (though more tedious) to override most setting so that they do not need to be preconfigured via `gcloud config set ...` and/or `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. For each setting one can specify environment variable.

For example the equivalent command you tried to use service account key file would be:

```
$ CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE=/etc/my-service-account-4b4b6e63aaed.json \
    gcloud alpha pubsub topics publish testtopic hello
```

Note that this will still cache credentials in `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` since it needs to cache access-token, so that it wont have to refresh it on each invocation.

For your use case best option in my view would be

1. Set `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` to some temp directory
2. `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=...`
3. ... use `gcloud` to do your work ...
4. Remove temp `CLOUDSDK_CONFIG` directory.

Comment: The `CLOUDSDK_AUTH_CREDENTIAL_FILE_OVERRIDE` was all I needed to get gcloud to recognize my custom creds json

Answer (score 9):

1) Create a ServiceAccount in GCP IAM. Check the box to "Furnish a new private key", and select JSON as the file type.

2) Download the JSON file to your server, and type:
`gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file serviceaccount.json`

3) Verify credentials were applied by running `gcloud auth list`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you look at the `--account` option? Like

```
$gcloud --account="foo" ...
```

([Reference](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/))

Regarding "Preferably without littering the file system with credentials files", I am not sure if it possible to achieve.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about how to authenticate without having to activate the service account credentials which caches the credentials elsewhere. I think you can only use `--account=` once the credentials have been activated.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have the env-var and json key, just run:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=$GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
```

this will activate the service account for gcloud/gsutil